# $k(\ln (k) - 1) = \ln (2n)$

Tags: probability

On the last page of

https://www.eecs70.org/static/notes/n17.pdf

I don't understand where the following claim comes from.

$\ln k! ≈ \ln 2n$ if $k$ is chosen to be $\ln n / \ln \ln n$

Can someone prove it / explain why $\ln n/\ln \ln n$ is a reasonable $k$ value?

Basically, why $\ln n/ \ln \ln n$ is a good choice for $k$ in the equality in the title? (The LHS is after applying Stirling's approx to $k!$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Stirling,

$$\ln k!\approx k(\ln k-1).$$

Then

$$\ln k!=\ln\frac{\ln n}{\ln\ln n}!\approx\frac{\ln n}{\ln\ln n}\left(\ln\frac{\ln n}{\ln\ln n}-1\right)=\ln n\frac{\ln\ln n-\ln\ln\ln n-1}{\ln\ln n}\approx \ln n$$

I have no convincing explanation for the factor $2$. I have the feeling that $k$ should have been chosen as

$$\frac{\ln 2n}{\ln\ln 2n}$$ though in practice this makes little difference.

---

**Numerical example:**

Let $n=10^9$.

We can take

$$k=\frac{\ln 10^9}{\ln\ln10^9}=6.837\cdots$$

or

$$k=\frac{\ln 2\cdot10^9}{\ln\ln2\cdot10^9}=6.989\cdots$$

Then in both cases, $7!=5040$ is a pretty poor approximation.